# How to plot relation in mathematica?

Tags: plotting

How to plot relation here?

I want to plot

```
-arctan(sin(x))*(x)+ arctan(sin(x))*(y)=sin[arctan(sin(x))*(y)+ arctan(sin(x))*(x)]
```

Comment: Please try to learn at least enough of Mathematica syntax to post your formulas in the language. Also, please learn how to vote (see the following comment)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: see `ContourPlot`

Comment: Contour plot is used to plot any f(x,y) on x-y plane ,that means the projection of that function ,, and a projection  is not a relation ,,, hope you get that @george2079

Comment: Maybe I should elaborate, see the second usage description on the `ContourPlot` documentation page.

Comment: Sorry, My mistake...actually being a novice i know a very much little of scripting in mathematica... @george2079

Answer (score 4):

```
eqn = -ArcTan[Sin[x]]*x + ArcTan[Sin[x]]*y == 
   Sin[ArcTan[Sin[x]]*y + ArcTan[Sin[x]]*x] // Simplify

(*  (-x + y) ArcTan[Sin[x]] == Sin[(x + y) ArcTan[Sin[x]]]  *)

Plot3D[Evaluate[{eqn[[1]], eqn[[-1]]}], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2 Pi, 
  2 Pi}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

```
Show[
 DensityPlot[Evaluate[eqn],
  {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi},
  PlotPoints -> 50],
 ContourPlot[Evaluate[eqn],
  {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi},
  PlotPoints -> 50,
  ContourStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, the `ContourPlot` could be done with `RegionPlot`

```
rgn = ImplicitRegion[{eqn, -2 Pi <= x <= 2 Pi, -2 Pi <= y <= 2 Pi}, {x, y}];

RegionPlot[rgn, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have taken the liberty of re-working your question. It may not be correct because of the uncertainty that you intended for parenthesis () versus square brackets, [].

I also moved the left hand side of your equation to the right hand side and defined a function.

```
f[x_, y_] :=  Sin[ArcTan[Sin[x]]*y + ArcTan[Sin[x]]*x] +
              ArcTan[Sin[x]]*x - ArcTan[Sin[x]]*y
```

Where this function is zero is the ***relation*** that you are looking for.

First let's simply plot it to become familiar with it.

```
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is possible to grab and rotate the plot to examine the region where it is zero.

To enhance that, add the plane where z = 0. This is accomplished by adding a new function of x and y that is simply zero.

```
Plot3D[{f[x, y], 0}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The solution can be shown directly using `ContourPlot`.

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]